# How to save progress on Quiz using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, save, progress

How are you doing?

I am working on a Quiz and am trying to listen the events of the user and save it to show them later based on the JSON file.

Look, each question is:

```
{
    "question": "How much is two plus two?",
    "option1": "Four",
    "option2": "Five",
    "option3": "Two",
    "feedback": "Good"
}
```

The "feedback", I would like to be saved and showed to the user only on the end of the Quiz.

Basically, it is to save their correct answers on the back, then show the "feedback" JSON variable at the end.

```
//i'm retrieving the value here, but what should I do with it?
var show = document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML;

//and appending the values on the words
```

[Check my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matheusloures/wovswes4/)

Here the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var questionNumber = 0;
 var wordNumber = 0;
 var questionBank = new Array();
 var wordsBank = new Array();
 var stage = "#game1";
 var stage2 = new Object;
 var questionLock = false;
 var numberOfQuestions;
 var score = 0;

 var data = {
     "quizlist": [

         {
             "question": "How much is two plus two?",
             "option1": "Four",
             "option2": "Five",
             "option3": "Two",
             "feedback": "Good"
         }, {
             "question": "Selecione a sentença correta",
             "option1": "I am a person",
             "option2": "I is a person",
             "option3": "I are a person",
             "feedback": "Bad"

         }, {
             "question": "Select the correct form in the interrogative",
             "option1": "Are you a student?",
             "option2": "Is you a student?",
             "option3": "You are a student?",
             "feedback": "Good"

         }, {
             "question": "How much is one minus one?",
             "option1": "Zero",
             "option2": "Two",
             "option3": "Four",
             "feedback": "Good"
         }, {
             "question": "He / She / It usam o verbo To Be ...",
             "option1": "is",
             "option2": "are",
             "option3": "am",
             "feedback": "Good"
         }, {
             "question": "Selecione a frase correta na afirmativa",
             "option1": "We are here.",
             "option2": "Are we here.",
             "option3": "We are not here.",
             "feedback": "Good"
         }, {
             "question": "Selecione a forma correta na negativa",
             "option1": "He is not here.",
             "option2": "He is not here?",
             "option3": "He are not here.",
             "feedback": "Bad"
         }, {
             "question": "You / We / They usam o Verbo To Be ...",
             "option1": "are",
             "option2": "am",
             "option3": "is",
             "feedback": "Good"
         }

     ]
 };
 numberOfQuestions = data.quizlist.length;
 for (i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
     questionBank[i] = [];
     questionBank[i].push(data.quizlist[i].question);
     questionBank[i].push(data.quizlist[i].option1);
     questionBank[i].push(data.quizlist[i].option2);
     questionBank[i].push(data.quizlist[i].option3);

     questionBank[i].push(data.quizlist[i].feedback);
 }



 displayQuestion();
 //gtjson



 //Display question and word, if correct
 function displayQuestion() {
     var feedbackMSG = questionBank[questionNumber][4];

     var rnd = Math.random() * 3;
     rnd = Math.ceil(rnd);
     var q1;
     var q2;
     var q3;
     var wordsShow = $('<li class= "center_txt"><p class="bluedark_txt big_txt">' + feedbackMSG + '</p></li>')

     if (rnd == 1) {
         q1 = questionBank[questionNumber][1];
         q2 = questionBank[questionNumber][2];
         q3 = questionBank[questionNumber][3];
     }
     if (rnd == 2) {
         q2 = questionBank[questionNumber][1];
         q3 = questionBank[questionNumber][2];
         q1 = questionBank[questionNumber][3];
     }
     if (rnd == 3) {
         q3 = questionBank[questionNumber][1];
         q1 = questionBank[questionNumber][2];
         q2 = questionBank[questionNumber][3];
     }

     //show the options
     $(stage).append('<div class="questionText">' + questionBank[questionNumber][0] + '</div><div id="1" class="option">' + q1 + '</div><div id="2" class="option">' + q2 + '</div><div id="3" class="option">' + q3 + '</div>');

     $('.option').click(function() {
         if (questionLock == false) {
             questionLock = true;
             //correct answer

             if (this.id == rnd) {
                 $(stage).append('<div class="feedback1">CORRECT</div>');
                 var show = document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML;
                 score++;

             }
             //wrong answer  
             if (this.id != rnd) {
                 $(stage).append('<div class="feedback2">WRONG</div>');
                 $("#words").append(wordsShow);
             }
             setTimeout(function() {
                 changeQuestion()
             }, 1000);
         }
     })
 } //display question




 function changeQuestion() {

     questionNumber++;

     if (stage == "#game1") {
         stage2 = "#game1";
         stage = "#game2";
     } else {
         stage2 = "#game2";
         stage = "#game1";
     }

     if (questionNumber < numberOfQuestions) {
         displayQuestion();
     } else {
         displayFinalSlide();
     }

     $(stage2).animate({
         "right": "+=800px"
     }, "slow", function() {
         $(stage2).css('right', '-800px');
         $(stage2).empty();
     });
     $(stage).animate({
         "right": "+=800px"
     }, "slow", function() {
         questionLock = false;
     });
 } //change question
});


function displayFinalSlide(){

    $(stage).append('<div class="questionText">You have finished the quiz!<br><br>Total questions: '+numberOfQuestions+'<br>Correct answers: '+score+'</div>');

}//display final slide



//doc ready
```

Would you help me?

I'm sorry the bad indentation, I am working to write it better!

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Totally forgot the displayFinalSlide(). Sorry

Comment: Please try to narrow your issue down to a [mcve] and include all of the relevant code in the question itself, not a third party site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the easiest way to do that is to hide #words with jQuery `$("#words").hide()` , and just show it after all question is answered with `$("#words").show()`
You didn't define function  displayFinalSlide, so now you can define it and on a final slide show user feedback, like we said:

```
function displayFinalSlide(){
 $("#words").show()
 $(stage).append('<div class="questionText">You have finished the quiz!<br><br>Total questions: '+numberOfQuestions+'<br>Correct answers: '+score+'</div>');

}
```

Working code on:
https://jsfiddle.net/58rmaaru/1/

Comment: Hey @t_dom93 , sorry about that. Forgot the **displayFinalSlide()** . Now corrected.

Comment: I also updated fiddle, it show feedback after user complete all questions! That was your question, right?

Comment: THANK YOU! You rock! By the way, do you know how to write so the user sees only the feedback + 1 (if the feedback repeats)? Like "Good [3]", "Bad [4]"

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create an array of user answers, and push a new object into it once we have decided whether their answer is right or wrong.  You haven't included logic for displayFinalSlide() in your fiddle, so I removed that call and just logged the array to the console so you can see it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

              var questionNumber = 0;
              var wordNumber = 0;
              var questionBank = new Array();
              var wordsBank = new Array();
              var stage = "#game1";
              var stage2 = new Object;
              var questionLock = false;
              var numberOfQuestions;
              var score = 0;

              var feedbackBank = new Array();

              var data = {
                "quizlist": [

                  {
                    "question": "How much is two plus two?",
                    "option1": "Four",
                    "option2": "Five",
                    "option3": "Two",
                    "feedback": "Good"
                  }, {
                    "question": "Selecione a sentença correta",
                    "option1": "I am a person",
                    "option2": "I is a person",
                    "option3": "I are a person",
                    "feedback": "Bad"

                  }, {
                    "question": "Select the correct form in the interrogative",
                    "option1": "Are you a student?",
                    "option2": "Is you a student?",
                    "option3": "You are a student?",
                    "feedback": "Good"

                  }, {
                    "question": "How much is one minus one?",
                    "option1": "Zero",
                    "option2": "Two",
                    "option3": "Four",
                    "feedback": "Good"
                  }, {
                    "question": "He / She / It usam o verbo To Be ...",
                    "option1": "is",
                    "option2": "are",
                    "option3": "am",
                    "feedback": "Good"
                  }, {
                    "question": "Selecione a frase correta na afirmativa",
                    "option1": "We are here.",
                    "option2": "Are we here.",
                    "option3": "We are not here.",
                    "feedback": "Good"
                  }, {
                    "question": "Selecione a forma correta na negativa",
                    "option1": "He is not here.",
                    "option2": "He is not here?",
                    "option3": "He are not here.",
                    "feedback": "Bad"
                  }, {
                    "question": "You / We / They usam o Verbo To Be ...",
                    "option1": "are",
                    "option2": "am",
                    "option3": "is",
                    "feedback": "Good"
                  }

                ]
              };
              numberOfQuestions = data.quizlist.length;
              for (i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
                questionBank[i] = [];
                questionBank[i].push(data.quizlist[i].question);
                questionBank[i].push(data.quizlist[i].option1);
                questionBank[i].push(data.quizlist[i].option2);
                questionBank[i].push(data.quizlist[i].option3);

                 questionBank[i].push(data.quizlist[i].feedback);
              }



              displayQuestion();
              //gtjson



              //Display question and word, if correct
              function displayQuestion() {

    var feedbackMSG = questionBank[questionNumber][4];

var rnd = Math.random() * 3;
rnd = Math.ceil(rnd);
var wordsShow = $('<li><p>'+feedbackMSG+'</p></li>');

var q1;
var q2;
var q3;

                if (rnd == 1) {
                  q1 = questionBank[questionNumber][1];
                  q2 = questionBank[questionNumber][2];
                  q3 = questionBank[questionNumber][3];
                }
                if (rnd == 2) {
                  q2 = questionBank[questionNumber][1];
                  q3 = questionBank[questionNumber][2];
                  q1 = questionBank[questionNumber][3];
                }
                if (rnd == 3) {
                  q3 = questionBank[questionNumber][1];
                  q1 = questionBank[questionNumber][2];
                  q2 = questionBank[questionNumber][3];
                }

                //show the options
                $(stage).append('<div class="questionText">' + questionBank[questionNumber][0] + '</div><div id="1" class="option">' + q1 + '</div><div id="2" class="option">' + q2 + '</div><div id="3" class="option">' + q3 + '</div>');

                $('.option').click(function() {
                  if (questionLock == false) {
                    questionLock = true;
                    //correct answer

                    if (this.id == rnd) {
                      $(stage).append('<div class="feedback1">CORRECT</div>');
                      var show = document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML;
                      score++;
                      feedbackBank.push({
                        question: questionNumber,
                        correct: true
                      });
                    }
                    //wrong answer  
                    if (this.id != rnd) {
                      $(stage).append('<div class="feedback2">WRONG</div>');
                       $("#words").append(wordsShow);
                       feedbackBank.push({
                        question: questionNumber,
                        correct: false
                      });
                    }
                    setTimeout(function() {
                      changeQuestion()
                    }, 1000);
                  }
                })
              } //display question






              function changeQuestion() {

                questionNumber++;

                if (stage == "#game1") {
                  stage2 = "#game1";
                  stage = "#game2";
                } else {
                  stage2 = "#game2";
                  stage = "#game1";
                }

                if (questionNumber < numberOfQuestions) {
                  displayQuestion();
                } else {
                  console.log(feedbackBank);
                }

                $(stage2).animate({
                  "right": "+=800px"
                }, "slow", function() {
                  $(stage2).css('right', '-800px');
                  $(stage2).empty();
                });
                $(stage).animate({
                  "right": "+=800px"
                }, "slow", function() {
                  questionLock = false;
                });
              } //change question
            });
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bigalreturns/dt6jvtnh/)

Comment: Hey @AlexYoung thanks! I forgot the **displayFinalSlide()**, now corrected. It should show the user the list of feedbacks after completion.